# Is this email for toll violations from CVM (Citations and Violations Management) a scam?

Tags: usa, driving, california, tolls

I got an email from CVM stating that I didn't pay a toll. I was told the bill was $106.  When I logged onto their website there was an administrative fee attached to it of $50 making the total $156.  I tried calling the number provided but nobody picked up.  I emailed them stating that I wanted to dispute the ticket but only received emails back stating that I needed to pay.  As I was traveling in California I did log onto THETOLLROADS.COM and pay my toll usage manually as was instructed by the car rental agency so that is what made me very skeptical of the email.  Anyway, I'm still trying to figure it out.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Who or what is "CVM?"

Comment: [This](https://www.bbb.org/us/ca/san-diego/profile/traffic-consultants/citation-violation-management-1126-172018630/customer-reviews) suggests it is a scam, where the rental company passes toll notices to a 3rd party company who tries to extort from you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you upload a scan of said letter with personal details blacked out? This would help us give you a better answer. If not, would it be possible for you to add more details such as their website or phone number?

Answer (score 3):

Car rental companies contract with private companies to collect tolls and tickets for traffic and parking violations.  There is commonly outrageous pricing related to this and the companies often have official sounding names.  For example, Avis/Budget uses Highway Toll Administration which has a official looking logo and official sounding name but is just a regular for-profit company.  CVM is just another of these companies.

It's possible whatever pre-payment you made for the rental vehicle didn't properly associate with your rental, or for whatever reason wasn't exactly correct, and now you're being billed & possibly fined for non-payment.  It's also possible the vehicle had a toll transponder which was billed and your payment didn't apply because it was based on the license plate.  If that's the case, you'll need to see if there are specific terms that cover this situation.

The bill from CVM should include information about specifically what you're being charged for so you should be able to confirm it matches whatever you actually drove.  Assuming it matches the time you had the rental car, the only way I can see getting out of the payment is if you can prove that you properly prepaid and successfully dispute the bill with the toll road operator (The Toll Roads of OC).

Answer (score 1):

Cvmsd is a third party company that works with ace rent a car to scam you. They add an administration fee to the actual cost of your violation they scare you and lie to you for you to make the payment through their company. If you want to resolve this matter you need to call the toll company that you are being charged from and give them the liscense plate number to check what the actual violation cost is. You can pay them and keep proof of payment if you want . Tbh you don’t even really need to pay jus leave it alone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I upvoted this answer because, though needing some improvement, it addresses the actual issue experienced by the OP.